# React giving no output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am learning to use react with babel, but the window is giving Blank page. I have used the necessary CDN links-

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id='app'></div>
  <script type="text/babel">
    class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (<div className = "app-content">
          <h1> Hey, this message is not SHOWING </h1>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to this CORS issue:
https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8515
You can't run it locally or with local files.  You might be able to use the non-minified version.

unpkg's @babel/standalone 7.x seems to have further problems.  Try using the 6.x version if you still have issues.  I've included it as a commented out script tag for reference.

Also, this is not meant for production use.  This is mostly just for playing around.  There's some valid use cases, but it's highly unlikely you match [any of them](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone#but-why).  Even in development, you should really be using a proper environment.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.js"></script>
<!--
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
-->
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id='app'></div>

</body>
    <script type="text/babel">
        class App extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return (
                    <div className="app-content">
                        <h1> Hey, this message is not SHOWING</h1>
                    </div>
                )
            }
            
        }
        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
    </script>
</body>
```